# Showing $x^n \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$ when $x > 1$ by contradiction

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I want to show that $x^n \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$ when $x > 1$. I know the usual direct proof that uses the Archimedean Property and Bernoulli’s Inequality, but I would like to find a proof by contradiction. Here is what I have so far:

Let $x > 1$ and suppose for contradiction that there is a $w$ such that $x^n < w$ for all $n > 0$. Then $x, x^2, …$ is a monotone and bounded sequence, so it will converge to a $y = \sup S$, where $S = \{x, x^2, …\}$.
Since $y - x < y$ we have that $y - x < x^k$ for some minimal $k > 0$. Then $y < x^k + x < 2x^k$, i.e. $x^n < 2x^k$ for all $n > 0$, and this quickly shows that $2$ is an upper bound of $S$. This leads to a contradiction when $x \geq 2$, but the case when $1 < x < 2$ is still unaccounted for.

Not sure where to go from here, or if there even is a complete proof in this direction. I would be happy to see other proofs that proceed by contradiction!

EDIT #1:
As Nick pointed out in the comments, instead of choosing $y - x$ as my non-upper bound, I could’ve chosen $y/x$, in which case $y/x < x^k \implies y < x^{k+1}$, a contradiction.

Comment: Instead of sandwiching between $y-x$ and $y$, choose an $x^k$ between $y/x$ and $y$. Then necessarily $x^{k+1}>y$. This covers $1<x<\infty$

Comment: @Nick Miracle worker.

Comment: You can also use a continuity argument: if $x^k\rightarrow y$, then $x^{k+1}\rightarrow xy$ as multiplication is a continuous operation. By uniqueness of limits, $xy=y$ which is only true when $x=1$ or $y=0$.

Comment: @AdamZ Or $y=\pm \infty$ and then $x$ can be anything positive, which is the actual case here.

Comment: @Ian Sure not a bad way to structure the proof too. I was using the hypothesis that $y$ is a real number as $S$ is assumed to be bounded for contradiction.

Comment: @AdamZ Ah yes, that makes sense. I couldn't tell at what stage of the proof you were inserting this suggestion.

Comment: @Ian Of course my bad for not being clear enough!

Comment: There is this one too. If $x, x^2, \dots$ converges to $w$, then $x^2, x^3, \dots$ converges to $xw$ my limit laws. But the latter is a subsequence of the former, so $w = xw$, which means that $x = 1$, a contradiction. Now by the contrapositive of MCT, the sequence cannot be bounded. This is probably similar to the suggestion by @AdamZ , but I am not sure what is meant by a “continuous operation” on a sequence. Is this just a reference to the sequential characterization of continuity? (In particular the constant-multiplication map is continuous.)

Comment: @AbcedDecba Yup I am referring to the sequential characterization of continuity

Comment: I appreciate this question's interest in discussing less popular ways to prove a well-known result. Imo, Adam's idea for completing the proof is the slickest but I might just be partial to the sequential characterization of continuity.

Answer (score 0):

This is really still the same idea that's already been presented by Nick in the comments, but I wanted to point out that you can already prove this by contradiction using only the least upper bound property, without appealing to limits or convergence (other than the definition of "$x\to \infty$").

If $x^n<w$ for all $n$, then as you suggest in your post the set $S = \{x, x^2, x^3 \dots\}$ has a least upper bound $y$.  Then $\frac{y}{x}<y$ is an upper bound for $\{1, x, x^2\dots\}\supseteq S$, and hence is a strictly smaller upper bound for $S$, a contradiction.

In other words, you need not look for a first $k$ in the sequence where things go wrong.